# Silent os.rename failure

Tags: python, linux

Let's say I have two files which are hardlinked to each other:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 2 mparrott grp 5 Jul 28 09:38 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 2 mparrott grp 5 Jul 28 09:38 foo
```

Then, I run this in python:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.rename('foo', 'bar')
```

I get no errors. But, listing the directory again, I still see `foo`.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 2 mparrott grp 5 Jul 28 09:38 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 2 mparrott grp 5 Jul 28 09:38 foo
```

It seems like this is happening because the files are indeed the same file (inode). However, I would still expect `foo` to be removed or an error to be raised.

Does anyone know why this is failing silently? My question is about the implementation itself rather than how to work around the problem (which I did using `os.path.samefile`). I'm on rhel 6.4.

Thanks!

Comment: This is how the operating system's `rename()` system call works. You get the same result if you do `mv foo bar` from the terminal.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be OS-dependent. On OS X `mv` works the same as `python`, on Linux `mv` does remove `foo`.

Comment: Actually, surprise suprise, `mv foo bar` does work! It's only os.rename which doesn't work.

Comment: `mv` must be doing something special, because I get the same result with `perl` and `php` as with `python`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `os.rename` function simply performs the `rename` system call. If the source and target are the same file, the system call does nothing silently. I get the same result as your Python script if I run the C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int result = rename("foo", "bar");
    printf("result = %d\n", result);
}
```

This prints `result = 0` and leaves both files.

This behavior is documented in the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html):

> If *oldpath* and *newpath* are existing hard links referring to the same
>          file, then `rename()` does nothing, and returns a success status.

This is also specified in [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rename.html):

> If the *old* argument and the *new* argument resolve to the same existing file, `rename()` shall return successfully and perform no other action.

Comment: Great, thanks for the notes and the alternative-language implementation. Very helpful.